# Android Studio release build with proguard: can't find referenced field in program

Tags: java, android, android-studio, proguard

this is the newest hot issue for every android pro coder. Will you shine in the glory of wisdom?

I got a warning from proguard. The class Appirater cause this warning:

> can't find referenced field in program class de.xxx.xxx.R.$id

From the proguard website
[proguard troubleshooting](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)

> A program class is referring to a field or a method that is missing
>   from another program class. The warning lists both the referencing
>   class and the missing referenced class member. Your compiled class
>   files are most likely inconsistent. Possibly, some class file didn't
>   get recompiled properly, or some class file was left behind after its
>   source file was removed. Try removing all compiled class files and
>   rebuilding your project.

A Build --> Clean --> Rebuild is not working.

If I add

> -dontwarn

the code compiles but the app crashes on startup.

To add the whole proguard.cfg from [the Appirater repo](https://github.com/drewjw81/appirater-android/blob/master/proguard.cfg) leads to no success.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
```

Comment: in my case it didn't help, I had to ignore it and test carefully that part of the app. I used: `-dontwarn com.sleepbot.datetimepicker.time.TimePickerDialog`